# How does RedirectToAction not hit my Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I've been seeing some unexpected behavour in my MVC application.

Lets say I have 3 action methods

- Details
- Details_Fr
- Details_En

The idea behind the 2nd and 3rd is that they switch the language and then redirect to the "real" Details action.

However, when I call RedirectToAction with a breakpoint in "Details" it is not reached.  This is the case when I visit the pages in this order "Controller/Details" and from there "Controller/Details_Fr".

Here are my actions:

```
    public ActionResult Details()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    public ActionResult Details_Fr()
    {
        this.SetLanguage(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA"));
        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }

    public ActionResult Details_En()
    {
        this.SetLanguage(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
```

I'm not looking for a solution as that's easily done by changing RedirectToAction to View(new MyViewModel()).  I am looking for an explaination so I understand what and why this is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: How does your route definition look like? This should work without any problem with the default routes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the language (CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture on CurrentThread) in ActionFilter attribute instead of creating those horrible _Fr and _En actions....!

Comment: Actually I do exactly that WHICH IS WHY I NEED RedirectToAction to actually Redirect (otherwise the Initialize is not called!)  All SetLanguage does is set the user's culture into a session variable so taht the Initialize routine can set the culture with each request.  Please read the question this isn't at all about culture its about learning more about RedirectToAction!

Comment: Check in Fiddler if your initial request to Details_Fr is coming back with HTTP 301. You can also verify the url.

Comment: I would suggest you create a single SetLanguage method that takes a culture and redirection as parameters.